# Getting error in setup of Existing Ionic 2 project on other Computer

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am getting error while 'npm install' on other computer.

npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.3
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @ionic-native/core does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/deeplinks@3.12.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/device@3.12.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/media@3.12.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/music-controls@3.4.4 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.1.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/social-sharing@3.12.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/splash-screen@3.1.0 wants @ionic-native/core@3.1.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/status-bar@3.1.0 wants @ionic-native/core@3.1.0

Please help.

Comment: assure that cordova, ionic and node version

Answer (score 0):

You should update latest node version and try again.

Please check below on that machine

```
node -v

ionic -v

cordova -v
```